# How do I show the whole text for a drop down box?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am using Windows Forms and C#. If my text is longer than the size of the drop down box, how do I show the whole text? In most cases the length is enough but for some cases it doesn't fit. Is there a property that I am missing to set this up?

[image]

Comment: you can make just the drop down portion wider without making the portion on the form wider.  Offhand, I'd say that is wide enough that the user gets the gist especially if they are canned messages

Comment: Oh how do I do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104571/winforms-combobox-problem

Comment: See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001450/allow-each-item-to-use-multiple-lines-in-a-winforms-combobox-or-listbox) if you want to go the route of something similar to text-wrapping on the combo box items.